# error in image path,image not showing in Wordpress post and pages

Tags: php, wordpress

it is showing

```
<img height="136" width="207" alt=" " class="portfolio" src="http://domain-name.com/wp-content/themes/Modest_v1.4/timthumb.php?src=http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6129/6021782390_76c3477fcd.jpg&h=136&w=207&zc=1&q=90" />
```

i want to use

```
<img height="136" width="207" alt=" " class="portfolio" src=http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6129/6021782390_76c3477fcd.jpg" />
```

i am using the following to display thumbnails but the src of images are not correctly returning:

```
print_thumbnail(
  $thumb,
  $thumbnail["use_timthumb"],
  $post_title,
  $width,
  $height,
  'Featured');
```

how i can do this.please help me.

Comment: I don't have a clue what you want to achieve. Please be more concrete. (My guess: your WP theme does this.)

Comment: ok. see the first line and see the src value in the image tag now see the second image tag and check its src value

Comment: So? This `http://domain-name.com/wp-content/themes/Modest_v1.4/timthumb.php?` does not magically appear. Go find out where it comes from (guess: your template). How are we supposed to know?!

Comment: I understood that "you want the path / src-value to be the second one". Other than that you are lacking essential information as to where this problem occurs. The above is obviously not handwritten, otherwise you'd change it yourself.
What generates the img tag? A plugin? Your template/theme?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a copy and paste error into your question here, but you're missing a double-quotes at the beginning of your `src=`

i.e:

```
<img height="136" width="207" alt=" " class="portfolio" src=http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6129/6021782390_76c3477fcd.jpg">
```

should be:

```
<img height="136" width="207" alt=" " class="portfolio" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6129/6021782390_76c3477fcd.jpg">
```

I could equally have mis-understood your question.. :o/

Comment: see the src value in first line and compare it with second one src="http://domain-name.com/wp-content/themes/Modest_v1.4/timthumb.php?src=http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6129/6021782390_76c3477fcd.jpg&h=136&w=207&zc=1&q=90"  AND src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6129/6021782390_76c3477fcd.jpg"

Comment: I can see there's a difference between the two `src=` lines, but they both look fine to me (they look like they'd both work) - what, exactly, is the problem you need help with? i.e. What happens that you're trying to change?

Comment: @amdrew first one is not working for me, i want the path to be as second one

Comment: i am using print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $post_title, $width, $height, 'Featured');  to display thumbnails but the src of images are not correctly returning , it is absolute.it shud be relative.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra - Thanks, I've added that code to your question - can you update it with the actual parameters you're using (please copy and paste from your post or page) - you need to give us more detail.

Comment: http://mae.neutronsoft.com please check the above link and http://mae.neutronsoft.com/?page_id=1108 both page are having the same problem